# How print text from web page on Bixolon mobile printer from android os

Tags: android, mobile, printing, bixolon-printer

description of the problem:
It is necessary to print on mobile printer Bixolon R200II from the mobile device which has operation system Android (V4.*). To be printed information is generated on the webpage, on which we log in from the existing browser ( though it may be Google Chrome) I want to print the information and how can it be performed.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set the mobile printer connected with your smartphone or tab together via bluetooth. For this yoi should turn on blutooth on Android and turn on your printer. Then press scan to search & find your mobile printer then click on the name that apperar on tablet and it ask you pin (its maybe 0000 or 1234 as a default) then tap ok button ..

Go to the webpage and send it to mobile printer it search to find it and then click print.